# How to force CKEditor inline widgets to preserve trailing spaces

Tags: ckeditor

As I reported at in this [CKEditor this ticket](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/605), inline widgets in CKEditor (4.7.0) do not preserve trailing spaces, causing display issues.

Take the following simple widget:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('spanwidget', {
    requires: 'widget',
    init: function (editor)    {
        editor.widgets.add('spanwidget', {
            editables: {
                content: {
                    selector: 'span'
              }
            },
            upcast: function (element) {
                return element.name == 'span';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When you load the following data `<span>lorem </span>ipsum`, you see this text in output: `loremipsum` (notice the missing space).

This can be seen [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cf5d457L/5/).

How can I work around the problem (I do not control which data is loaded inside CKEditor)?

Comment: According to the ticket, this is supposed to be fixed in CKEditor 4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to force the last trailing space to be preserved. The idea is to replace the last space with a `&nbsp;` when upcasting the widget element, then remove it before downcasting it:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ck', {
  allowedContent: true,
  extraPlugins: 'spanwidget'
});

CKEDITOR.plugins.add('spanwidget', {
    requires: 'widget',
    init: function (editor) {
      editor.widgets.add('spanwidget', {
        editables: {
          content: { selector: 'span' }
        },
        upcast: function (element) {
          // Matches?
          if (element.name == 'span') {
            // Ends with text?
            var children = element.children,
              childCount = children.length,
              lastChild = childCount && children[childCount - 1];
            if (lastChild instanceof CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text) {
              // Replace the last space with a non breaking space
              // (see https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/605)
              lastChild.value = lastChild.value.replace(/ $/, '&nbsp;');
            }
            // Match!
            return true;
          }
          // No match
          return false;
        },
        downcast: function (element) {
          // Span with class "targetinfo"?
          if (element.name == 'span') {
            // Ends with text?
            var children = element.children,
              childCount = children.length,
              lastChild = childCount && children[childCount - 1];
            if (lastChild instanceof CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text) {
              // Ends with a non breaking space?
              var match = lastChild.value.match(/&nbsp;$/i);
              if (match) {
                // Replace the non breaking space with a normal one
                lastChild.value = lastChild.value.replace(/&nbsp;$/i, ' ');
                // Clone the element
                var clone = element.clone();
                // Reinsert all the children into that element
                for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                  clone.add(children[i]);
                }
                // Return the clone
                return clone;
              }
            }
          }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

See [updated JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tuk1y92j/).